# Awk -- subsititute text in specific location

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following script:

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

FileName=$1;
awk '
/Import()/
{
    while (sub(/\$requestedMessage/, "bar") == 0)
    {
        print;
        getline;
    }
}
1' > file.tmp $FileName
```

And the following file:

file:

```
function FunctionA()
{
    message=$requestedMessage
}

function FunctionB()
{
    message=$requestedMessage
}
```

The idea is to call

```
./script.sh file
```

and to replace the `message=$requestedMessage` variable in function `FunctionB()` to `message=bar` but only in `FunctionB()` and not `FunctionA()`

I am very new to AWK and I don't seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '
/FunctionB\(\)/ {
    sub(/\$requestedMessage/, "bar")
}
1' "$FileName" > file
```

Maybe this is more like what you had in mind:

```
awk '
/^function/ { inTarget = (/FunctionB\(\)/ ? 1 : 0) }
inTarget { sub(/\$requestedMessage/, "bar") }
1' "$FileName" > file
```

If not - how do you know when you reach the end of a function definition? The above assumes you know one function has ended when the next function definition begins.

Comment: Hi That works! But when I seam to add endlines before "{" and after "}", to try and understand your code, it stops working... Can you explain in your answer how this  works a bit?

Comment: Also can we do this without the use of RS and ORS since it will make the soultion "file" dependant

Comment: You can't put a newline before the `{` as that completely changes the meaning of the script. Whitespace matters in awk scripts. I put a couple of newlines in where they can go. You can write a different script to do what you want without setting RS and ORS but I don't understand what you mean when you say setting them `will make the solution "file" dependant` - what file and why?

Comment: Hi I mean your solution now depends on the format of the file. The only assumption I have is that I have a file containing many functions and all functions contain this sentence "message=$requestedMessage" and I would like to change it to message=bar only in 1 specific funtion

Comment: You can't write a script to parse text that's independent of the format of the text. How do you know in general where a function name appears as the start of a function vs the call to a function or a comment? How do you know when you reach the end of a function? You should update your sample input to better reflect your real world cases if it currently doesn't do that.

Comment: I added something that may be more like what you were looking for.